# How can I select colums from multiple tables and display it in yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I'm working on Yii framework for PHP web development. Now I have to select data from more than four tables and display it as a single table using join.
   Suppose, I have created model classes for tables test1,test2,test3,test4  each containg two columns. I need to display a table which contains the columns of all the four tables.
How can i do this in yii framework

Comment: are all tables related to each other ??

Comment: @ninad Yes they are all related

Comment: @Ninad The query is something like - "Select a.id,b.id,c.id,d.id from test1 a,test2 b,test3 c,test4 d where a.id=b.id and c.id=d.id"

Comment: @Ninad Where can I modify my query for this

Comment: When u create a model for these default relations are created refer to those relations to display result

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to join models using a search in a single model. It works but its much better to understand relational tables.

```
 public function searchItems($id)
    {
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->join .=' LEFT JOIN tbl_items as items ON od.ItemId = items.Id';
    $criteria->join .=' LEFT JOIN tbl_taxes as taxes ON t.ShippingState = taxes.State';
    $criteria->together = true;


    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,

    ));
}
```

You can then call this as your dataprovider by using:

```
$model->searchItems(whatever you want to pass it);
```